# Firestore returning undefined documentSnapshot.createTime (using webproject with javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I try to get the timestamps `createTime` and `updateTime` as described in the [DocumentSnapshot Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#data). So far i have done the following:

- successfully connected firestore with my javascript webproject
- read and write data works

Thats my code trying to get the timestamps:

```js
db.collection("users").doc("user1").get().then(doc => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log(doc.createTime);  // -> undefined (?)
        console.log(doc.updateTime);  // -> undefined (?)
        console.log(doc.readTime);    // -> undefined (?)
        console.log(doc.exists);      // -> true (works)
        console.log(doc.id);          // -> "user1" (works)
    } 
}).catch(error => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

How come that the document timestamp methods are not working, whereas the other methods like `exists` or `id` work properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `createTime` and `updateTime` you linked are available when your code runs in Cloud Functions, using the `firebase-functions` library.

Since your code is not running in Cloud Functions, these properties are not (currently) available. You should use the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) to know what properties are available for you in the regular JavaScript SDK.

Comment: ups totally have not seen that, thanks for clarification and the correct link.

Answer (score 0):

The document of Firebase for web is this.

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.html
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js